# java array pass by reference does not work?

Tags: java

I thought almost all languages, including java, pass array into function as reference (modifiable).

But somehow it does not work here, and the `testArray` is still `1,2,3` with size of 3.

Strange enough, when if I change `result[i] = 2` to `a[1] =2` it works. It did pass by reference.

What is wrong with this code?

At the end, I had `a = result`; (which update the a). Did result get removed from stack. Is that why I still get to the original `a`?

I am confused.

Thanks!

```
class Test
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {

      int[] testArray = {1,2,3};
      equalize(testArray, 6);

      System.out.println("test Array size :" + testArray.length);
      for(int i = 0; i < testArray.length; i++)
         System.out.println(testArray[i]);
   }

   public static void equalize(int[] a, int biggerSize)
   {
      if(a.length > biggerSize)
         throw new Error("Array size bigger than biggerSize");

      int[] result = new int[biggerSize];
     // System.arraycopy(a, 0, result, 0, a.length);
     // int array default value should be 0
      for(int i = 0; i < biggerSize; i++)
         result[i] = 2;

      a = result;
   }
}
```

Comment: Please explain your logic in details. Are you trying to expand you array size? Currently your result array doesn't copy any values from original array.

Comment: Have you seen <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference>?

Answer (score 52):

The array is passed by reference, but the *reference* is passed *by value*. That is, you can change the array that `a` refers to, but you cannot change *which array `a` refers to*.

Answer (score 7):

Java is pass by value. This is why your code does not work. A good practice would be to mark `int[] a` as `final` so this would result in a compilation error (see the corresponding [Checkstyle rule](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_misc.html#FinalParameters)).

Answer (score 5):

return parameter "a" from the function and assign to testArray in the main function. When you pass an object by reference, the reference is copied and given to the function. So the object is now referenced by 2 references. Any changes in the object through the 2nd reference will reflect in the first reference, because it is the same object referenced by both of them. But when you change the reference (not the object through reference), it is a different case. you have changed the 2nd reference to point to another object(int[] result). So any changes through the 2nd reference will change only the "result" object.

```
class Test
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {

      int[] testArray = {1,2,3};
      testArray = equalize(testArray, 6);

      System.out.println("test Array size :" + testArray.length);
      for(int i = 0; i < testArray.length; i++)
         System.out.println(testArray[i]);
   }

   public static int[] equalize(int[] a, int biggerSize)
   {
      if(a.length > biggerSize)
         throw new Error("Array size bigger than biggerSize");

      int[] result = new int[biggerSize];
     // System.arraycopy(a, 0, result, 0, a.length);
     // int array default value should be 0
      for(int i = 0; i < biggerSize; i++)
         result[i] = 2;

      a = result;
      return a;
   }
}
```

Comment: is it possible though to have void ( or not returning anything ) ? thanks

Comment: The new array is created inside the function. So it should be returned. - Recommended approach.
There are some other approaches like initialize the result array outside and pass it as 3 rd parameter or define 3rd parameter as Hashmap and put result array inside.

Answer (score 4):

When you do **a = result;** object **a** dosnt anymore point to the **testArray**, bc you are changing its reference to **result's** address. That's why it dosnt effect anymore to the **testArray**.
What you are doing actually is you are making **a** the same adress as **result** has, so whatever you change in **a** it will change in **result** too.

Hope this helped...

Answer (score 2):

The array referenced by `a` can be modified, but the reference itself is passed by value.  So if you did `a[0] = 1`, then you would be changing the original array.  However, `a = result` changes the reference, and so the original reference is unchanged.

Comment: hmmm any idea to implement my function? basically i want to resize my array from 3 to 6 :(

Answer (score 1):

[Java is pass by value](http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm), always.

Comment: the answer i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are Objects in java. If you have initialized your array with a size(actually length), you cannot modify it. You can create a new Array with a varying size (as you are currently doing in the function ) and copy all the values from the Old Array to the new Array. In your case, you have 2 objects and 3 references. If you want to access the Array of greater size in the calling function , make the function return the reference of the Array of greater size.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class test
{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] a = {15, 2, -3};
        printArray(a);
        changeArray(a);
        printArray(a);
    }
    private static void changeArray(int[] a){
        for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
            a[i]++;
        }
    }

    private static void printArray(int[] a){
        for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
            System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

-----OUTPUT-----

15 2 -3

16 3 -2

Comment: Some sort if explanation is always good to go with code